# How to like facebook community in iphone using graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I am developing a Facebook application on iPhone which displays feed from a community. I can access wall of the community using the Graph API using the link http://graph.developer.com/CommunityID/feed?
and also post comment & like for particular wall post using graph POST api  http://graph.developer.com/CommunityID_WallpostID/comments? & http://graph.developer.com/CommunityID_WallpostID/likes?

Now my problem is to "Like" the community first, which I was not able to find in Facebook's documentation

Has anyone successfully implemented this using graph API or other API?

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now Facebook doesn't allow you to like anything apart form posts through Graph API. We actually had a work around using webview to display Facebook Like button.

You can refer to this great post by Ray Wenderlich at http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

and customize your like button at http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box

Hope it helps.